# How to create an alarm wake screen in android and disable default back button?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alarms

Hello every one I request you to please give me the solution of this question .
I have created a alarm wake up screen when alarm started it has two buttons *snooze* and *dismiss* and it work fine . 
But the problem is started when user press the back button on phone it disappears from the screen
and sound is still playing. If anyone have solution please provide me.
Thank you

This is AlarmService class

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class AlarmService extends Service {

    public static String TAG = AlarmService.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmScreen.class);
        alarmIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        try{
        alarmIntent.putExtras(intent);

        getApplication().startActivity(alarmIntent);

        AlarmManagerHelper.setAlarms(this);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(" May be null intent found if not snooz or dismiss the button by user on alarm screen");
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    }

}
```

and this one is receiver class that create an alarm screen

```
public class AlarmScreen extends Activity{

    public final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    private WakeLock mWakeLock;
    private MediaPlayer mPlayer;

    public static final String ID = "id";
    public static final String NAME = "name";
    public static final String TIME_HOUR = "timeHour";
    public static final String TIME_MINUTE = "timeMinute";
    public static final String TONE = "alarmTone";
    public static final String NOTE = "note";
    public static final String USER = "user";

    static String name;

    static String note;

    static String userName;

    static String tone;

    static int timeHour;

    static int timeMinute;
    private static final int WAKELOCK_TIMEOUT = 60 * 1000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Setup layout
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_screen);

        /*parentView.getBackground().setAlpha(128);*/
        name = getIntent().getStringExtra(AlarmManagerHelper.NAME);
        note = getIntent().getStringExtra(AlarmManagerHelper.NOTE);
        userName = getIntent().getStringExtra(AlarmManagerHelper.USER);
        timeHour = getIntent().getIntExtra(AlarmManagerHelper.TIME_HOUR, 0);
        timeMinute = getIntent().getIntExtra(AlarmManagerHelper.TIME_MINUTE, 0);
        tone = getIntent().getStringExtra(AlarmManagerHelper.TONE);

        TextView tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alarm_screen_name);
        TextView tvNote = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alarm_screen_note);
        TextView tvUser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_nameUser);
        tvName.setText(name);
        tvNote.setText(note);
        tvUser.setText(userName);
        TextView tvTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alarm_screen_time);
        tvTime.setText(String.format("%02d : %02d", timeHour, timeMinute));

        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        final int screenWidth = (int) (metrics.widthPixels * 0.50);
        final int screenHeight = (int) (metrics.heightPixels * 0.50);

        // Get instance of Vibrator from current Context
        final Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        // Start without a delay
        // Each element then alternates between vibrate, sleep, vibrate, sleep...
        long[] pattern = {0,800,200,1000,300,1000,200,4000};

        if (v.hasVibrator()) {
            Log.v("Can Vibrate", "YES");
        } else {
            Log.v("Can Vibrate", "NO");
        }

        Button dismissButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.alarm_screen_button);
        dismissButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mPlayer.stop();
                v.cancel();
                finish();
            }
        });

        //adding snooz button
        Button btn_snooz = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_snooz);
        btn_snooz.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mPlayer.stop();
                v.cancel();
                sooz_activity();
                System.out.println("Snooz Activity Started");
                finish();



            }
        });

        //Play alarm tone
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            if (tone != null && !tone.equals("")) {
                Uri toneUri = Uri.parse(tone);
                if (toneUri != null) {
                    mPlayer.setDataSource(this, toneUri);
                    mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
                    mPlayer.setLooping(true);
                    mPlayer.prepare();
                    mPlayer.start();
                    v.vibrate(pattern, 0);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Ensure wakelock release
        Runnable releaseWakelock = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);

            //  getWindow().setLayout(screenWidth, screenHeight); 
            /*  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);*/



                if (mWakeLock != null && mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
                    mWakeLock.release();
                }
            }
        };

        new Handler().postDelayed(releaseWakelock, WAKELOCK_TIMEOUT);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Set the window to keep screen on
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);

    //  getWindow().setLayout(screenWidth, screenHeight); 
        // Acquire wakelock
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        if (mWakeLock == null) {
            mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), TAG);
        }

        if (!mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
            mWakeLock.acquire();
            Log.i(TAG, "Wakelock aquired!!");
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mWakeLock != null && mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
            mWakeLock.release();
        }
    }


    public void sooz_activity(){
        PendingIntent pIntent = createPendingIntent(this);

        long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long nextUpdateTimeMillis = currentTimeMillis + 5 * DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS;
        Time nextUpdateTime = new Time();
        nextUpdateTime.set(nextUpdateTimeMillis);
        setAlarm(this, nextUpdateTimeMillis, pIntent);
    }

    private static PendingIntent createPendingIntent(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
        //intent.putExtra(ID, model.id);
        intent.putExtra(NAME,name);
        intent.putExtra(TIME_HOUR,timeHour);
        intent.putExtra(TIME_MINUTE,timeMinute);
        intent.putExtra(TONE,tone);
        intent.putExtra(NOTE,note);
        intent.putExtra(USER,userName);
        return PendingIntent.getService(context,1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private static void setAlarm(Context context, long nextUpdateTimeMillis, PendingIntent pIntent) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextUpdateTimeMillis, pIntent);
        } else {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextUpdateTimeMillis, pIntent);
        }
    }

}
```

and it works fine but when alarm screen appears on the phone main screen and user just pressed the default phone back button it disappear from the main screen and the sound and vibration continue until i go to stop running task.

Comment: post the code of what you tried

Comment: you could override `public void onBackPressed() {}` to make back button do nothing

Comment: either you can override onBackPressed() or can mediaPlayer.stop() on activity destroy

Comment: @Mr Neo and Survivor thank you very much both of you .. it's working fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you got to do is override onBackPressed().

Android studio autocompletes this code as you type onBackPressed().

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() // Declare in the activity showing the alarm screen

{
     // code here what should be done at back button press

     super.onBackPressed();  // This line handles the default action of back button
}
```

Before super.onBackPressed(), you may do something like snooze or something.

Also you can use onPause() or similar ones as the other guy said. (Refer Activity lifecycle)

Hope I cleared your doubt. Let me know if you got further doubts.

Answer (score 0):

I think "The New Boston" has a great video to help with understanding what is going on here. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-G91Hp3t6sg
you might be looking for onPause() to stop the sound. 
I think the video would be a good starting point for monitoring how your app is behaving in different states.

Comment: thank you @Michael Dimmitt but i don't have to stop that audio.. instead i write  onBackPressed(); ..